# Cannot install text_normalizer on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-normalization

I tried to pip install text_normalizer via Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3) or Jupyter Notebook and keep getting the same error

I logged in as Admin. pip3 is not recognized either. Not sure what else to try.

```
C:\Users\username>pip install text_normalizer==0.1.3
Collecting text_normalizer==0.1.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/98/b49628d90d5793e7369e25d6a84f9ca4a1fc6472d848d15daa9bf9129ad7/text-normalizer-0.1.3.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\nlp\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n646z_1p\\text-normalizer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n646z_1p\\text-normalizer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n646z_1p\text-normalizer\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n646z_1p\text-normalizer\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        long_description = f.read()
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 712: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: "Check the logs for full command output." what are the logs saying ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was working with the example from the book "Text Analytics with Python: A Practitioner's Guide to Natural Languagecessi Processing, Second Edition
by Dipanjan Sarkar, 2019." and had to connect to text_normalizer.py instead of loading the text_normalizer package. The file was missing in the example. 
Thank you very much for your prompt reply